# Can I use probe to monitor a static target and collect metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, prometheus, prometheus-operator

Hej, developers. There is a static URL of a target that I want to monitor via the Prometheus operator. For some reason, I don't know the label name of the service or namespace. I found probe CRD may can help me to get a metrics from a static target. But there are no docs or example to help me to make a probe yaml. Can anyone help me with a probe example? the example ip could be 0.0.0.0:8080.

PS: I tried to use EndPoint to point to the static target, unfortunately it only can point to a ip address not a domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this: just set the prober same with the target. TBH, I can not understant why prober should be set same as target. but it is works.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Probe
metadata:
  name: probe-sample
  namespace: monitoring

spec:
  interval: 5s
  jobName: probe-sample
  scrapeTimeout: 2s
  prober:
    url: example.com:8080
    scheme: http
  targets:
    staticConfig:
      static:
      - example.com:8080
```